# i keep getting Cannot GET / on heroku after deploying my system

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, deployment

as the title says i keep getting Cannot GET / after i deployed my system there , so when i type heroku logs i get these 2 errors :
first

```
(node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

even tho i fixed my parameter variables for both development and production servers , to connect using mongoose i have process.env.MONGODB in the code and it is working correctly on the development server.

the second error is

```
(node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

and it doesnt have a reference to the specific code or line or file to know where the mistake is exactly

and these are my Dependencies for the system

```
{
 "name": "task-manager",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "start": "node src/app.js",
   "dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/app.js"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.3.0",
   "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
   "express": "^4.17.1",
   "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
   "mongodb": "^3.6.2",
   "mongoose": "^5.10.9",
   "multer": "^1.4.2",
   "sharp": "^0.26.2",
   "validator": "^13.1.17"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
   "nodemon": "^2.0.5"
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

so as a reference in case anyone face the same problem in the future, i found the answer already , i had 2 problems there.

The first is that my IP address was the only IP whitelisted on the MongoDB Cluster , so i edited it to make all IP's because heroku will use a different IP address than mine , i made it 0.0.0.0/0 to whitelist all Ip's.

The second problem was the timeout because there are 2 await functions in a route with another function in between and that is sending emails to users , so i moved that function after the second await so the server doesn't reply with a timeout , because obviously with these 3 functions it causes a timeout specially sending emails as i read in Heroku Documentations.